# How to fix Error: The argument type 'void Function(String, int)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(String, int?)' because 'int?'

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

**Here is the error:**

The argument type 'void Function(String, int)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(String, int?)' because 'int?' is nullable and 'int' isn't.
codeSent: (String verificationID, int resendToken) {
^

**Here is my code:**

```
verifyPhone() async {
var widget;
await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
    phoneNumber: "+91${widget.phone}",
    verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) async {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance
          .signInWithCredential(credential)
          .then((value) async {
        if (value.user != null) {
          Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Profilescreen()),
              (route) => false);
        }
      });
    },
    verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {
      print(e.message);
    },
     codeSent: (String verificationID, int resendToken) {
      setState(() {
        _verificationCode = verificationID;
      });
    },


    codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationID) {
      setState(() {
        var verificationCode = verificationID;

      });
      },
    timeout: Duration(seconds: 60));
```

}

Thank you!

Comment: Dont forget to set the answer as valid in order to close this topic, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are tons of similar questions on SO. The issue is coming from the null safety feature adding the nullable types noted with a question mark `int?`.

You need to use the correct type just as putting a `String` into an `int`. Here you need to adapt you code in order to provide the correct types.

Sometimes you can use non nullables everywhere, perform manual checking, etc. You can read more about it [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/null-safety).

Regarding your issue, I'd say you have to modify you anonymous function `codeSent`:

```
(String verificationID, int? resendToken) => ...
```